# Time Created Date 8 hours behind

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

When i try to check my SQL server for SharePoint, I've notice that the time created value is not correct on the SQL server, 8 hours behind from the real one which is 1/17/2017 11:38 AM . Image below:

This is on my SQL Server
[image]

This the data from Sharepoint

[image]

Can you help me with this, Thank you.

Comment: That must be reflecting the timezone of the server where it is located than your timezone

Comment: I check my Timezone for each server and its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date values stored in SQL will be UTC rather than the local timezone. This would mean you're UTC+8.

Comment: but how do i know that? The time of my SQL Server is right, but the Time Created is not.

Comment: If it is the SharePoint UI you're looking at, then as stated above, it is a Regional Settings issue. If you're looking at the database tables (you shouldn't), the values are stored in UTC, not the local TZ.

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to site settings > regional settings.

(url - `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx`)

2) Set your time zone as per your region.

3) Click Ok at the bottom. Then your time will be reflected correctly.

By default, it is set at Pacific Standard Time.

[image]

Comment: My time zone is (UTC+8 ) Kaula Lumpur, Singapore.  Yes the time zone on my SharePoint is corect but the record inside the database is not.